# IPv6 in IPv4 over LAN

Tags: linux, networking

I want to setup IPv6 in my LAN, but also want to have some machine to use IPv4 only. How do I do such setup so that every machine can communicate with each other ?

All machines supports dual-ip stack.

Comment: All machines support dual-stack, but do all machines have IPv4 addresses?

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is to use dual-stack.  Give all devices IPv4 addresses.  Devices that support IPv6 will likely already have configured themselves, but will need some help to communicate with each other.  Setting up a zeroconf (avahi, bonjour, etc) server will help them find each other by name.

If your IPv6 provider (Tunnel Broker, or ISP) have provided you with a routeable address block setup `radvd` to help them autoconfigure addresses.  `radvd` can also be used to distribute the address of your DNS servers.

You will need a good firewall as IPv6 is not protected from Internet access by a NAT device.

Comment: NAT does not protect you from the Internet either. What you think is NAT protecting you is actually a built in firewall on the NAT device. Whether NAT or no, a firewall is the *only* thing providing the protection.

Comment: @bahamat NAT to private addresses does prevent direct access to the devices behind it (except for those that are port forwarded to).  As such it is an effective firewall for incoming connections.  IPv6 does not offer such protection.

Comment: No, that's the firewall. NAT without a firewall is just a router and I can get to the inside if I am one hop away and craft the right packets. NAT != firewall.

Comment: @bahamat On the stateful NAT configurations I have used if you can craft the right packets, you are likely already passing through.  The firewall further limits which port can pass in or out.

Comment: The first part where you're talking about "stateful" that's a firewall. The second part where you're talking about which packets can pass in or out, that's also a firewall. NAT usually implies a firewall but NAT != firewall. Just like a car always comes with seat belts, it's not the seat belts that allow you to drive. Don't confuse one with the other.

Comment: @bahamat I think you are confusing connection tracking for a IP Masquerading (which enables hosts on private addresses to connect to the Internet) with connection tracking for firewalling.  IP Masquerading is not firewalling, but both can use the same connection tracking data.  DNAT which is not IP Masquerading can be used to pass in through the firewall.

Comment: I'm not confusing anything. You're assuming that just because on Linux NAT and packet filtering are done with the same tool that NAT is somehow a security thing. NAT is NOT for security. NAT is NOT a packet filter. NAT is usually implemented *in conjunction* with packet filtering but *do not confuse them*.

Comment: @bahamat I am fully aware that fixed NAT does not provide any security.  The use of private (non-Internet routeable) addresses does provide security in the absence of any incoming NAT rules.  The stateful source NAT typically used for IP masquerading in this case tends to be secure, and to the best of my knowledge is not Linux specific.  Firewalling does not provide private addesses access to the Internet, NAT does.  I'll leave it at that.

Comment: If you have private IP's and are using IPMASQ I *can* still enter your network if I know the inside range and am one hop away. The ***only*** thing that can prevent this is a packet filter. NAT alone **does not** provide **any** protection in that case.

Comment: Route filtering?

Comment: Route filtering drops packets that don't match the routing table. But the scenario I describe above properly complies with the route table and therefore won't be dropped.

Comment: Not on my network.  The only valid incoming addresses on the external network are my external addresses.  Likewise for valid sources outgoing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3978/discussion-between-bahamat-and-billthor)

Answer (score 0):

Set up the IPV4-only machines specially.  E.g. using NetworkManager to disable IPV6 on the LAN connection.  Done.

If they're mobile... I don't think you can tie those settings to a given wired network, at least not in the GUI.  In that case you may have to accept the machines are mangled and will not work on IPv6-only nets.

They'll talk to each other just fine.  Mainly over IPv4 :) if you're using linux MDNS for name resolution (.local addresses with Avahi).  I have a feeling the same may apply with Samba (Windows-compatibility network software).  Hopefully `systemd-resolved` will be more IPv6-aware.

But this seems a really arbitrary question ("some of my machines are religious objectors to IPv6").  It would be nice to indicate reason(s) for this requirement so we could help you more.  If there's a way to avoid mangling your machines this would generally be preferable.